# How to remove parent category after removed child on slug

Tags: wordpress

the following function remove child category from slug, but what code integrate to remove parent category too?

```
function wpse147453_remove_child_categories_from_permalinks( $category ) {
while ( $category->parent ) {
    $category = get_term( $category->parent, 'category' );
}
return $category;
}
add_filter( 'post_link_category', 'wpse147453_remove_child_categories_from_permalinks' );
```